# Different between transaction vs request in AWS IOT limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cloud, iot, aws-iot

In most of the official documents to express throttling limits, AWS uses metrics like **Requests per second** or **Requests per client**. e.g. [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-request-throttling.html). But for [AWS IOT API throttling limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html#limits_iot), there are using a metric called **Transactions per seconds**. Is there an actual difference between "Transactions per Second" and "Requests per second" metrics or they are just the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They mean the same thing — the rate in which you're allowed to call the API. It seems there's no standard for this term; it's chosen at the discretion of the writers. Some services only state a plain number, i.e. `1000`, others use `requests`, and a few use `transactions`.

Comment: Yes, I talked to AWS customer representative, and she said the same thing. Thanks for answering.